# when clicking on the fab button how to play the last played video in video player?

Tags: java, android

Actually, I'm Developing a Video player. then I have small Requirement for the video player i.e., whenever my video player application is launched when clicking on the fab button how to play the last played video? Please anyone can help me..

Comment: When User Play Vedio Save It`s Uri In SharedPrefernce  In Key 
for Example "lastVedio"  And Then get it and Play it

Comment: store last played video data(like path of video and time to be resumed) in sharedPref .

Comment: Create a temp file which stores the path of last played video , and when you click on fab button you can play that video

Comment: Thank you jyothi, but  if you don't mine please provide sample

Comment: Thank you java fan if you don't mine please provide sample

Comment: Thank you Elsunhoty, if you don't mine please provide sample

Comment: @Ashok you can refer [**`this link`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Store your last played video uri or file path some where in shared preference or in database.
and on click play that uri or file in your video view. like below example
Ask anything if you not getting my point.

Store last Video :

```
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref",0);
    Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("LastVideo", "path or Uri"); // Store your last video uri or file path
    editor.commit();
```

Get last video :

```
String path = pref.getString("LastVideo", null); // getting String
```

You will get you last uri or path into path variable.

Answer (score 0):

Hai Priyank Actually How to Add the Volume Increase and Decrease options using seekbar on Swipeup(); and swipe down on onToucheventListener. I have no idea to add the above functionality if possible please tell me the process or please provide the sample Priyank.